# gradle project sync failed android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to setup [nhaarman/ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/) inside of Android Studio 1.1.0.

From Setup:

Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
}
```

yet Android Studio says:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing,
>   debugging) will not work properly.

```
Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'X' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: I have imported this project a month ago. Did you try clicking on Apply Gradle Plugin?

Comment: I did and I got list of plugins and Gradle is not in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding those lines to:

`build.gradle (Module: app)`

instead of

`build.gradle (Project: app)`

the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding these dependencies in **the top level** `build.gradle` file.

You have to add these lines in the module `build.gradle` file.

```
root
  build.gradle   //top level
  app
     build.gradle   //module level
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @arr. worked for me.

```
//ListView Animations
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0'
```